# JSF 2 composite component editableValueHolder dynamic name

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

Is there any way to define a dynamic "name" attribute for editableValueHolder in the composite component.

e.g.:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="name" required="false" default="text"/>
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="false"/>
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="#{cc.attrs.name}" targets="textId"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="textId" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" validatorMessage="Error"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

then let the page auther to use my tag like:

```
<my:inputText value="whatever" name="testText">
    <f:validateLength for="testText" minimum="20"/>
</my:inputText>
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: how I can do that? I try this but without luck I didn't get any exception but the validater didn't work.
the "name" attribute in the editableValueHolder must be static to work. I can't use EL to evaluate it at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the text from a bean and initialize your component with it.

```
<my:inputText value="whatever" name="#{yourBean.getDynamicText()}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moved the "editableValueHolder" tag as a child tag for the "implementation" tag. it seems that EL will not evaluate the expression in the "interface" tag.

Thanks all for your help.